# How to print out a word from string with speccific first letter?

Tags: java, string

I'm having a problem with printing out a specific word from a string variable in java. My task is to make a program that prints out every word that starts with a letter (T).

It looks like this.

```
String names = "Tony,May,Anna,Thomas";
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What problems do you encounter?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(names.split(","))
      .filter(name -> name.startWith("T"))
      .forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: looks like a homework question :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
 String names = "Tony,May,Anna,Thomas"; 
 String[] arrOfStr = names .split(",", 5); 

        for (String a : arrOfStr){
        if(a.startsWith("T"))
        System.out.println(a);
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Tony
Thomas
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String names = "Tony,May,Anna,Thomas";
Arrays.stream(names.split(",")).filter(s -> s.startsWith("T")).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```